Асинхронное соединение с mysql
синхронное соединение использует MySQLdb и успешно подключается, при этом асинхронное соединение использует pymysql и aiomysql, но не подключается, выводят ошибку sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
url для асинхронного соединения 'mysql+aiomysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db'
url для синхронного  'mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db'
async_engine = create_async_engine(
    url = conf.db.database_url,
    echo = True
)
async_session = async_sessionmaker(async_engine)

проверил через aiomysql напрямую:
import aiomysql
async def test_connection():
    try:
        # Установка соединения с базой данных
        connection = await aiomysql.connect(
            host='127.0.0.1',
            port=3306,
            user='root',
            password='password',
            db='db',
            charset='utf8mb4'
        )

        # Проверка подключения
        if connection:
            print("Успешно подключено к базе данных!")

        # Закрытие соединения
        await connection.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка подключения к базе данных: {e}")

# Запуск асинхронной функции проверки подключения
asyncio.run(test_connection())

вывод:
Ошибка подключения к базе данных: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'")
